# Adding Conda Python libraries to cc_binary in Bazel to embed Python via Pybind11?

Tags: anaconda, bazel, pybind11

I am trying to embed Python into a C++ application using Pybind11. I have added Pybind11 into my Bazel distribution, similar to what is described here in the [Pybind11 Bazel repo](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_bazel). My project is similarly formatted to [this example](https://github.com/lwdhw1987/bazel_pybind11_embedding/tree/master).

However, while Bazel compiles this fine, I keep getting a runtime error of `dyld[69334]: symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyBaseObject_Type'`. I'm not sure what is causing this; it seems like the Python libraries are not being linked somehow?

In the Pybind11 repo, they mention that:

> @pybind11//:pybind11_embed currently supports Python 3 MacOS/Ubuntu/Debian environments:
>
> pyenv
> pipenv
> virtualenv
>
> If pybind11_embed doesn't work with your embedded Python project, add @pybind11 as a dependency to your cc_binary and follow the instructions for manually retrieving the build flags.

Considering I use Conda, I wonder if this could cause an issue? If so, would I need to manually specify the Conda-installed Python library paths in Bazel somehow?

Comment: Maybe a missing runtime dependency that need to be added to the `data` attribute?